# Nextjs Component-Level CSS Module not being applied

Tags: css, next.js

I'm trying to import a component-level CSS module (xx.module.css), but it is not being applied. I am using Nextjs and using a custom server.js, _app.js, and _document.js. I am suspicious that I need to do something in one of those files to make the CSS load, but I do not know what it is. Is anyone able to guide me?

Styled code:

```
import styles from "./NavigationButtons.module.css";
...
<div className={styles.test}>
<>Some text here I want colored</>
</div>
```

NavigationButtons.module.css:

```
.test {
    color: "red";
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, the color value should be `red` (no quotes), i.e. `color: red;`.

Comment: Ok, I feel like an idiot. Thank you so much. (Switching between inline css for react and regular css files had me off)